# Can I set up two installations of Ubuntu as dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot

As a web developer, a lot of the work I'm doing is in `/var/www`, not in `/home`. I’m shortly moving to part time work, and one option the company is considering is having someone else use my PC while I’m not here, but it’s hard to see how another web dev could use it without getting mixed up with my git branches and suchlike. One option, of course, would be to set up two different installations in VirtualBox, but a simpler might be an Ubuntu/Ubuntu dual boot setup, if that’s possible. How would I go about this?

Comment: 2? You can have dozens if you want :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, just like any dual boot system with different linux distros or with Ubuntu and Windows, you can have two Ubuntu installations alongside each other.

But there might be problems with security, unless the systems are encrypted, and it might be complicated to install two encrypted systems alongside each other in the same drive. One solution can be that you and the other user (of the same computer) install your Ubuntu systems in external drives, for example SSDs connected via eSATA or USB 3.

Such installations will be straightforward, if no internal drive is connected, when Ubuntu is installed, for example according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).